# Is it possible in Dreamweaver MX to put my own background color to my code?

Tags: colors, background, dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver MX I am trying to go to edit - preferences, but it only target tags and not entire code, can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Dreamweaver, as far as I know it should also work way back in Dreamweaver MX (currently *7* versions old), if it is not present, then you can't change the code background color:
Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences, Code Coloring category. Change the value for "Default background" to modify code view background color.

Comment: No not really what I was looking for. I want to highlight different parts of my code different color. eg. First table green and then second table blue. Don't know if I am making sense.

Comment: No that is not possible as far as I'm aware.